# Databricks connection to Cosmos DB Mongo API

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect to Cosmos DB Mongo API from Databricks and I get the error,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON String: &#39;&#39;
```

Option 1:

```
data = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").option("Endpoint", "https://cosmosdb-myendpoint.com:443/").option("Masterkey", "primary key of the account").option("Database", "sample").option("Collection", "sample1").load()
```

Option 2:

```
cosmosConfig = {
  "Endpoint" : "https://cosmosdb-myendpoint.com:443/",
  "Masterkey" : "primary key of the account",
  "Database" : "sample",
  "Collection" : "sample1"
}

cosmosdbConnection = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**cosmosConfig).load()
```

Both these options give the same invalid JSON string error.
I've already installed the library on the cluster.

Comment: Are you using the correct Spark Driver? https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I had installed the SQL API connector. I got it working through the Spark MongoDB connector available through Maven. 
Maven coordinates: org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.1